# System Call C++ with Weka

Tags: c++, weka

I'm writing a C++ project that will occasionally use a `system` call to Weka to get some machine learning information. First I'd like to ensure that the training model (`training.model`) is up to date. So, at the beginning of main, I call:

```
system("\"java weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -t ML_data.arff -d training.model\"");
```

That gives `Error: could not find or load main class weka.classifiers.trees.J48`. I know what that means, so I moved the entire Weka project folder, entitled `Weka-3-6`, to the directory in which my project is found. So then I tried:

```
system("\"java \Weka-3-6\\weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -t ML_data.arff -d training.model\"");
```

But that returns `Error: could not find or load Weka-3-6\weka.classifiers.trees.J48`.

I feel like I'm in the right neighborhood, but I can't get the slashes right, and I'd prefer not to mess with absolute paths because the folders have spaces and that makes it even messier. Any ideas? Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal/cmd prompt and try to run your command in your terminal/cmd prompt. Following is an example cmd batch script for windows. Your problem is most likely java classpath settings not weka problem. If you succeed in following command, then try your command with again in c++.

```
SET WEKA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Weka-3-7
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASPATH%;%WEKA_HOME%\weka.jar
SET HEAP_OPTION=-Xms4096m -Xmx8192m
SET JAVA_COMMAND=java %HEAP_OPTION%
%JAVA_COMMAND% weka.core.SystemInfo
```